# How do you find characters in an NSArray and return YES in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to find "Worf" inside the array of strings and then returning the BOOL of "YES" if I do find it, but if not, then return a BOOL of "NO".

So far this is what I have but it isn't working.

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"Worf", @"son of Mogh", @"slayer of Gowron"];
NSString *myWorfString = @"Worf";
BOOL yesOrNo = NO;

for (NSString *task in myArray) {
  if ([task isEqualToString: myWorfString]) {
  yesOrNo = YES;
  return yesOrNo;
} else {
  return yesOrNo;
}
```

How would I input "return [myArray containsObject:myWolfString];" into my equation?

Comment: When you say "inside"... do you mean that it's a member of the array, or that it's a substring of one of the members of the array?

Comment: Sorry I mean the I want to be able to return YES if Worf was detected, being that if it would also be detected if it were a string "Worf is cool" for example.

Comment: Ok. Then see my new answer below. It should be faster than the NSPredicate method because it doesn't involve allocating a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways you can find characters in NSArray and return YES in objective-c:-

1) By using `NSPredicate`

```
NSPredicate *pd=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self MATCHES[CD] %@",myWorfString];
BOOL yesOrNo=[[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:[[myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pd]count]]boolValue];
```

2) Second using `containsObject`api

```
BOOL yesOrNo = [myArray containsObject:myWorfString];
```

3) Refer `@EricS` answer

Comment: The NSPredicate code has worked for me, however i'm a little confused on how it works, is it possible if you can explain it to me? :)

Comment: Basically, NSPredicate is a Foundation class that specifies how data should be fetched or filtered. Refer this link it will help you http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

Answer (score 2):

First of all you shouldn't compare objects with `==` unless you know what you are doing, since it compares memory addresses (where they are allocated) and not the contents. So two NSString* which points to two different instances which contain the same value are not equal according to `==`.

You should use `isEqualToString:` or `isEqualTo:`.

In addition NSArray already contains this functionality, you don't need to reinvent the wheel:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"Worf", @"son of Mogh", @"slayer of Gowron"];
BOOL yesOrNo = [myArray containsObject:@"Worf"];
```

Comment: How would I put this in all my code to my it correct? I'm a little confused on this part.

Answer (score 2):

You have a logic error - you return immediately if the first item in the array is not @"Worf". While others have proposed solutions that will work, this one is most like your original code:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"Worf", @"son of Mogh", @"slayer of Gowron"];
NSString *myWorfString = @"Worf";

for (NSString *task in myArray) 
  if ([task isEqualToString: myWolfString]) 
    return YES;

return NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Never compare strings with `==` use `isEqualToString:` instead.

You can just write:

```
return [myArray containsObject:myWolfString];
```

If you need to also check substring, you can use `NSPredicate` :

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"Worf", @"son of Mogh", @"slayer of Gowron"];
NSString *myWolfString = @"Worf";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS [c] '%@'",myWolfString]];
NSArray *filteredArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

if ([filteredArray count])
{
    NSLog(@"Index Of Object in main Array : %lu",(unsigned long)[myArray indexOfObject:filteredArray[0]]);
}
```

Comment: If the OP wants to find entries in the array that contain exactly the string he's looking for (e.g. "Worf") that'll work fine. If an array entry might contain a substring (e.g.e "Lt. Worf, the Klingon Star Fleet officer") that won't work.

Comment: @DuncanC: Even if he try to use isEqualToString: it won't work then, for that he need to use NSPredicate. From his question I don't think he need that functionality

Comment: For substrings you could also use indexOfObjectPassingTest and write a custom comparator block that would detect the substring match.

Comment: I agree with @DuncanC on this one, I have read some things on NSPredicate, but i'm not sure on how to use it.

Comment: @TonyTaiNguyen: If you need that one, then you need to try it first. Anyway I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than go through the items one at a time, you can search the array concurrently, with lots of searches happening in parallel.

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"Worf", @"son of Mogh", @"slayer of Gowron"];
NSString *myWorfString = @"Worf";

__block BOOL searchStringFound = NO;
[myArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(NSString *string, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([string isEqualToString:myWorfString]) {
        searchStringFound = YES;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

What's the advantage of this? It's faster, rather than search the array serially, you are doing it concurrently. Okay, so in this instance with such a small array it's unlikely to make much difference, but for larger arrays it could.

It's also a useful technique to use when looking for objects in collections. Because once you have found the object, you just set the `stop` parameter to `YES` to signal that no more enumerations need to be performed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a substring:

```
- (BOOL)array:(NSArray *)array containsSubstring:(NSString *)substringToSearchFor
{
    for (NSString *string in array) {
        if (! [string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            continue;  // skip objects that are not an NSString

        if ([string rangeOfString:substringToSearchFor].location != NSNotFound)
            return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"Worf", @"son of Mogh", @"slayer of Gowron"];
NSString *myWorfString = @"Worf";
BOOL yesOrNo = NO;

for (NSString *task in myArray)
    {
        if (([task isEqualToString: myWorfString]) || ([task rangeOfString:myWorfString].location != NSNotFound)) {
            yesOrNo = YES;
            break;
        }
    } 

return yesOrNo;

Above code will return either array will contain as string or substring in array.
```